# How can I create this UI in flutter? please help me out :

Tags: flutter, dart

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQYu0.png
I'm new to flutter, and I've been trying to build this ui but it's way out of my league !
Here's my code so far:
(by the way I didn't use any specific package...)
My biggest challenge are the angles of that circle !
How can I create that circle? Is there a package for it ?

```
class NowPlaying extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NowPlayingState createState() => _NowPlayingState();
}

class _NowPlayingState extends State<NowPlaying> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,

      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: btmGreen,
            height: 60,
            width: size.width,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
GestureDetector(
  child:
  cbutton(back),
  onTap: (){
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>NowPlaying()));
  },
),
                Spacer(),
                Container(
                  height: 35,
                  width: 300,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    //    topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(260)),
                   color : PrimaryGreen,

                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
         //   color: Colors.white,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                buildVerticalMenu(size),
      ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(370),
        child: Container(
          color: Orange,
          height: 400,
          width: 400,
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(370),
            child: Container(
                // padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(110, 110, 0.0, 110),
                height: 360,
                width: 360,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: PrimaryGreen,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(200)),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/hiphop.jpg"),
                  ),
                ),),
          ),
        ),
      ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
 Widget buildVerticalMenu(Size size){
    return Container(alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(60)),
              color: Colors.white,
      ),
      height: size.height*0.3,
      width: 70,
      child: RotatedBox(

          quarterTurns: -1,
          child: Text('Now Playing', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20 , fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,color: PrimaryGreen),)),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please share the code that you have written so far, and where do you need help exactly.

Comment: Thank u , i edited my question and added my code

Comment: If you are new to Flutter you should start of by making something simple.

Comment: It's been like 4month or so that i've started flutter , so i decided to challenge my self with more complex ui...that's why I want to make this one

Comment: please focus in your question on one issue, either the ui angles of the circle and create another question with an example regarding to responsive views. Please take some reasearch on SO first, there are a lot of examples out